# Will it hurt my chances of getting another PhD if I leave my current ESRC funded one?

Tags: phd, funding

I have an ESRC scholarship for my current PhD, but my relationship with my supervisor has broken down and I can't make progress. If I leave this PhD, will that harm my chances of getting a different PhD or funding?

Comment: Please explain to the international community what is "ESRC", as the majority of users would not have heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am also in the UK looking to see what my options are about starting a new PhD. I am STFC funded, but am (but more was) curious about ESRC work.I emailed ESRC about this and got this response:

> ... For more information about our DTPs and CDTs visit: https://www.ukri.org/councils/esrc/career-and-skills-development/funding-for-postgraduate-training/

> https://www.ukri.org/publications/esrc-postgraduate-funding-guide/

> Just to add a final point, in addition to the guidance my colleague highlighted previously, please note that as per p10-11 of the Postgraduate Funding Guide: *Students who have already received government funding for Master’s-level or PhD-level training may apply for further funding but the total length of funding available plus previous government funding will not normally exceed four years for full-time study (or the part-time equivalent).*

They also said this earlier in the email chain:

> In particular, you should be aware that ESRC ‘does not expect its
> funding to be used for students who have already completed a
> substantial proportion of a PhD… Studentships should not normally be
> awarded to students who have already had a period of full-time
> postgraduate training at the same or higher level, or employment that
> is the equivalent of such training, unless support for them would
> clearly represent a good investment of public funds… taking into
> account the individual circumstances and other applicants for the
> limited number of ESRC awards. (p. 11)’ In other words, a student who
> had already received UKRI studentship funding would have to make a
> highly persuasive case that further support was justifiable and
> represented good value.  I’m only able to give you highly generic
> advice. You might find it helpful to discuss your situation with
> student services in your institution or other sources of postgraduate
> support.

At least within science, I am getting a vague impression that if I finish my current PhD I can apply for another. It's not ideal, I'd prefer to simply switch, but it may mean I get a second chance at being able to aim for something I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to another CDT and similar PhD programs see excellent answer by @RealDisinformation.

Otherwise, I don't see a strong relevance to the organization that funds your PhD here (in this case ERSC). What important is your track record and CV. If you drop out from a PhD program and then apply to another one without a good explanation ("falling out with my supervisor" is probably the least desirable explanation to potential supervisors), then this may be flagged by the PhD admission committees and potential supervisors.

On the other hand, this is not saying it is will be impossible to get a new PhD post, assuming either the admission committee does not know about your previous PhD program or you have a good explanation for dropping out.